# Django ORM for mutual follow query

Tags: django

```
user_id   user_follow
3             2
3             2
3             2
2             3
```

login `user id=3`, now i want to get people who follow me and i follow them, mutual follow in django framework for login user. above senario show login `user(id=3)` follow the `user(id=2)`
and `user(id=2)` also follow the login `user(id=3)` now I want to show to login user, how many user follow you and you follow him. using django orm

```
class Cause(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cause_creator_set')
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User)


class Attendance(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    cause = models.ForeignKey(Cause)
    user_follow = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    follow = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s is attending %s" % (self.user.username, self.event)

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name_plural = "Attendance"
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use a ManyToMany relationship through the ORM?

Comment: yes. but give the queryset for above senario. How i get mutuall follow username and show them to login user, that these people follow you and you follow them

Comment: There's nothing very special about the above scenario (besides the unexplained duplicates), but sure I'll give you an explanation (if no one beats me to it)

Comment: hahahaha. Brother give me. GOD BLESS U. you can assume that above table as mutual.object.all() and User.object.all() for login user

Comment: Yeah it would be beneficial if you'd also share your models.py.I could give you a more specific answer

Comment: i have post the models.py

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here, I'm going to try and address them all.

1. The relationship your models describe is what called a [`Extra field on ManyToMany relationship`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Simply put, Cause has a ManyToMany to User, with Attendance being an intermediatry table. The benefits of using the `through` instruction for this are mostly for ease-of-access, and you can read the documentation I linked for examples. So:

   ```
   attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Attendance')
   ```
2. Now let's talk about Attendance. I have a problem with two fields:

   ```
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   user_follow = models.IntegerField(max_length=255)
   follow = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   ```

   Yes, I showed 3 because only 2 of them are problematic. So you have a ForeignKey to User, right? But what *is* a ForeignKey? It's simply an IntegerField that points on the row (pk) on a different table. There are other stuff that happens here, but the basic thing is *it's just an integerfield*. And then you wanted to link that model to user again, right? So instead of adding another ForeignKey, you *used an IntegerField*.

   Do you understand why that's a bad thing? I'll explain - you can't use the ORM on your own logic. Now the basic thing I'm assuming you are trying to accomplish here is actually this:

   ```
   # let's pretend that User isn't built-in
   class User(models.Model):
       follow = models.ManyToManyField('self')
   ```

   Then there's the `follow` Boolean which I really don't get - if a user is linked to another one, doesn't that automatically mean he's following him? seems more like a method than anything.

   In anyway, I can think of two very valid options:

   - Use another ForeignKey. Really, if that what makes sense, there's nothing wrong with multiple ForeignKeys. In fact, it will create a sort of ManyToMany from user to himself going through Attendance as an intermediary table. I think this makes sense
   - Create your own User class. [Not a terribly complicate feat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). I also recommend this, since it seems you have plenty of customization. The built in User is great because it comes pretty much out of the box. But at the same time, the built-in user is pretty much built around the admin interface and kinda limits you a lot. A custom one would be easier. Then you can do the [recursive relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships) that seems to be what you're looking for, then implament `is_following` as a boolean method (seems more appropriate).
3. The last thing I'm gonna do is show you the method you're looking for. I'm showing you how to do it though as I mentioned, I strongly recommend you first take my suggestion and build your own User model. The method would look different of course, but it wouldn't be hard to convert.

   That being said, the key here is simply creating two methods - one for checking if a user is related. A second one for checking if you're being followed by him. So if I understand you correctly, you're trying to achieve:

   ```
     #using your way
       def follows(a, b):
           if Attendence.objects.filter(user__pk=a, user_follow=b).count() > 0:
               return True
           return False

       def mutual(a, b):
           if follows(a, b) and follows(b, a):
               return True
           return False

       a, b = 2, 3
       mutual(2, 3) # will output True


     #using a custom User Class:
      class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
          # required fields here...
          follow = models.ManyToManyField('self')

          def is_following(self, user):
              if user in self.follow.all():
                  return True
              return False    

          def mutual(self, user):
              if self.is_following(user) and user.is_following(self):
                  return True
              return False
   ```